# Find all paths between two nodes using cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, depth-first-search, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am using the graphing library cytoscape.js and want to find a way to get all paths (not just a single shortest path for example) between two nodes.

My initial thought to do this is to perform multiple iterations of depth first search to get all of the paths, each time removing those found edges so as to not get picked up by the next DFS iteration.

Is there a better way using cytoscape to do this?

Cheers

Comment: For what do you want to get all paths?  There may be a simpler, more efficient way of getting the end effect you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @maxkfranz . I have a graph which represents a task dependency visualiser, displaying tasks and their prerequisites in order to run. Starting at the root node, there may be multiple paths through different nodes leading to the target node, which form the dependencies, and I would like to know all those paths so I can change their colour and make them stand out.

Comment: From looking a bit further into the documentation, it looks I should be able to get this using out of the box functionality. The library offers the ability to get predecessors and successors, which recursively gets edges into and out of a given node respectively. I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: As long as it's a DAG, those functions make sense for that usecase.

Comment: Hi @TophatGordon - could you please share your code that give all paths between two nodes ? Cannot figure out how to make it.